# Update SQL with JQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have an RSVP box on my website where I want people to click the tick or cross image depending on whether they are coming or not. I currently have a PHP system that updates a SQL database but it reloads the page.

I have tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'attending',
        success: success
    };

    // bind to the form's submit event
    $('.attending').click(function {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });

    function success(responseText, $form) {
        $(".attending").hide();
        $(".success").fadeIn();
    } 
});
```

The RSVP buttons are links with  tags
But I am strugling with this, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Check the error console for JS errors.

Comment: You're missing parentheses after the `.click` function, it should read `.click(function() {`

Comment: What specifically is your issue with the code? When using the code you've posted, is it simply not working and not submitting at all (jquery errors)? Is the page still reloading (meaning your binding isn't working)?

Comment: $('.attending').click(function(e) {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    e.preventDefault();
});

your click event has some syntax error.

Comment: Yes, the page keeps reloading and the database is not updating either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajaxSubmit function is part of the [jquery forms plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) ... are you including that plugin with the page? (You didn't tag the question with jquery-forms-plugin, so I'm guessing no) If this is your first go at jQuery ajax, I'd recommend using the .ajax method first, even though it's more lines of code, to get an understanding of what's going on there.

Comment: I have used your idea and it has worked perfectly, thank you! The only issue is that the img:hover tag doesn't work once the rsvp has been clicked. I can provide a link to the site if you need.

Comment: Sure, provide the link and I'll take a look-see.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the brackets after declaring the function in your click handler, try this:

```
// bind to the form's submit event
$('.attending').click(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

Or better yet:

```
// bind to the form's submit event
$('.attending').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
});
```